# Merge multiple Rails applications with the ability to enable/disable each one of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, architecture

I've multiple Rails projects and I need to merge them into one Application with the ability to enable/disable each one of them with license that I'll provide to user; any ideas about best approach/tools to do so ?
FYI:there are common models and functionalists between these projects.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to make one of them as an engine. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: Though i have been voted down for my answer but check this out http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines?view=asciicast. It will give you the ability to enable/disable the each one and keep the code seperate for each of them. So its like you can have one Single application in which these two app are mounted.

Comment: Not sure why anyone down voted your answer, +1. This is the approach I took at my company when creating a CRM program. One app had the logic, and I created the rest as an engine.